# How to add input text validation for true and false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends, i can't figure it out how to add text validation for `admin` var.
Point is user enters either `0` or `1` or `true` or `false` in the form. It's ok  with checking numbers but i can't make up valid check for text input, e.g. true-e-e-e, fasleee, abra-cadabra, etc.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitEmployeeForm() {             

        // getting the employee form values
        var name = $('#name').val().trim();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var admin = $('#admin').val();
        if(name.length ==0) {
            alert('Please enter name');
            $('#name').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(age <= 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid age');
            $('#age').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(admin < 0 || admin > 1)  {
            alert('Please enter 0 for false, 1 for true');
            $('#admin').focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };  
</script>
```

I tried the following 2 options:

```
!admin.isEqual("false") || !admin.isEqual("true")

admin.valueOf()!="true" || admin.valueOf()!="false"
```

as a result is it does not pass any text including true and false.

Comment: isEqual is JAVA, not JS. `if (admin)` will be false if admin == blank, null undefuned or 0

Comment: Just use a couple of radio buttons/drop-down menu options for your admin field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept only `'0','1','true','false'` as valid then use something like this

```
if (['0','1','false','true'].indexOf(admin.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        alert('Please enter 0 for false, 1 for true');
        $('#admin').focus();
        return false;
}
```

What we do is create an array which holds the valid texts, and then use `indexOf(parameter)` which searches the array for any element matching the passed parameter. If it is found it returns the position it was found in the array, if not it returns `-1`. So in your case if it is -1 which means that the passed value was not one of the accepted then do your thing.

---

Alternatively, you could use a checkbox instead of a text box, and just test if it is `checked` property is true.

Comment: i tried
 (['0','1','false','true'].indexOf(admin.toLowerCase()) > -1)
, now it accepts all but '0','1','false','true'

Comment: @svorobei you are right.. i didn't notice what you were doing inside the if. Just changes `<-1` to `==-1`

Comment: @svorobei i updated the answer with a short explanation of what we are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following:

```
if (admin == true || admin == false || admin == "true" || admin == "false") {
    //if you want to convert -> convert it, and send to server
} else {
    //Wrong input
}
```

(More at [here](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table).
This is an equality table for values if you use == instead of ===)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't just check if it's 1, 0, true or false but using logical AND like this:

```
if(admin != 0 && admin != 1 && admin != "true" && admin != "false"){
    alert('Please enter 0 for false, 1 for true');
    $('#admin').focus();
    return false;
}
```